# Where to store license information that I will need at multiple levels?

Tags: c#, state, .net-6.0

I'm developing .Net 6 API.

My project includes controllers, services and repositories (using dependency injection).

I also added a permission check via middleware:

**Program.cs**

```
app.UseMiddleware<AuthMiddleware>();
```

**AuthMiddleware.cs**

```
public class AuthMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<EcmAuthMiddleware> _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public AuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, 
      ILogger<AuthMiddleware> logger, IConfiguration config)
    {
       _next = next;
       _logger = logger;
       _config = config;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IUserApiService 
     userApiService)
    {
        ...
        context.Items["Instance"] = instance;
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

From here I get the customer (and database) to run the APIs on.

Now I need to get some license information (via external API) from the newly obtained client and store it somewhere.

I tried invoking the call from the controller but would have to repeat it for almost all controllers. So I thought about transferring the call to middleware.

From the call I will have various information that I would like to store for use by the underlying levels: controllers, services and repositories. I'd rather not use the session or coookie.

Can I use only httpcontext or are there other solutions?

```
context.Items["LicenseInfo"] = licenseInfo;
```

This information is valid only for the call of an api then it should not be stored (eg Application).

EDIT:
GetLicenseInfo() must contains an external call:

```
string result = await _userApiService.GetUserApiResponseAsString("users/token", HttpMethod.Get, applicationId, token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use only httpcontext or are there other solutions?

There's nothing wrong with using `HttpContext.Items` for this. It's exactly what `HttpContext.Items` is *for:* attaching contextual data to an HTTP request. With this kind of "dictionary of objects" API, I do like to wrap my own APIs around it for type safety and simplicity:

```
public static class HttpContextLicenseInfoExtensions
{
  public static void SetLicenceInfo(this HttpContext context, LicenseInfo licenseInfo) =>
      context.Items[key] = licenseInfo;
  public static LicenseInfo? TryGetLicenseInfo(this HttpContext context) =>
      context.Items[key] as LicenseInfo;
  public static LicenseInfo GetLicenseInfo(this HttpContext context) =>
      context.TryGetLicenseInfo() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("No license info.");

  private static readonly string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
}

// Example middleware
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
  context.SetLicenseInfo(licenseInfo);
  await next.Invoke();
});

// Example usage
var licenseInfo = HttpContext.GetLicenseInfo();
```

But if you *really* want to avoid `HttpContext.Items`, you *can* use `AsyncLocal<T>`. You just want to structure the API so that you set the value for a specific scope (I like to return `IDisposable` to un-set the value), and then you usually inject an "accessor" to read the current value. Something like this should work (using `Disposable` from my disposables library):

```
public static class AsyncLocalLicenseInfo
{
  public static IDisposable Set(LicenseInfo licenseInfo)
  {
    var originalValue = local.Value;
    local.Value = licenseInfo;
    return new Disposable(() => local.Value = originalValue);
  }

  public static LicenseInfo? TryGet() => local.Value;

  public static LicenseInfo LicenseInfo => TryGet() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("No license info.");

  private static readonly AsyncLocal<LicenseInfo> local = new();
}

// Example middleware
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
  using var localValue = AsyncLocalLicenseInfo.Set(licenseInfo);
  await next.Invoke();
});

// Example usage
var licenseInfo = AsyncLocalLicenseInfo.LicenseInfo;
```

If you don't like the `static` API, you can hide it behind an "accessor":

```
// Inject this into downstream types
public interface ILicenseInfoAccessor
{
  LicenseInfo LicenseInfo { get; }
}

public sealed class LicenseInfoAccessor : ILicenseInfoAccessor
{
  public LicenseInfo LicenseInfo => AsyncLocalLicenseInfo.LicenseInfo;
}

// Example usage
var licenseInfo = licenseInfoAccessor.LicenseInfo;
```

Comment: Sorry but it's very difficult to understand AsyncLocalLicenseInfo. My fault. LicenseInfo must be different for different requests.

Comment: @Emanuele: It will be different, since it's set in the middleware.

Comment: I put in the httpcontext. Then I will evaluate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is only an alternative to MiddleWare which might be a better option, might not, it depends on a lot of things (as in most software dev questions).

This could be the factory:

```
public class LicenseInfoFactory
{
    public LicenseInfoFactory(IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
      _context = context;
    }

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;

    public LicenseInfo Build()
    {
        _context...
        // api call to get/build/return LicenseInfo
    }
}
```

And then in your startup:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddSingleton<LicenseInfoFactory>();
services.AddScoped<LicenseInfo>(provider => { 
   var factory = provider.GetRequiredService<LicenseInfoFactory>();
   return factory.Build();
});
```

Then just inject `LicenseInfo` in your controllers/repositories constructors etc:

```
public MyController(LicenseInfo licenseInfo)
```

This should only make one api call [per scoped request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes). (this is from memory, syntax might not be exact)

Comment: Updated the answer, since you need access to httpcontext you dont want to make the factory static. Also be aware, the factory as a singleton.

Comment: Sorry but AddSingleton is for every object and every request. According to me it's wrong.

Comment: But remember your factory shouldnt hold state IMO. So a singleton should be ok. If it needs to hold state, then use Scoped. All depends on your factory code.

Comment: So I just create and return LicenseInfo?

Comment: Yea, simple as that. Then you should have `LicenseInfo` available where ever injection is taking place. Again, this is from memory, so will need lots of testing.

Comment: In the Build method I need to call an external API but the method can't be async?

Comment: I think that would be out of the scope of this question, I'd ask another question for that.

Comment: I already edited the first post. Maybe the factory isn't the right solution. Maybe I can create a class and not a string instance and move all info to httpcontext item.